# sharepoint rest api file upload works when I have console open and breakpoints enabled

Tags: 2013, rest, file-upload, api

This is strange, but this is my current scenario

I am using this script and HTML

```
<script>

    'use strict';

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        // Check for FileReader API (HTML5) support.
        if (!window.FileReader) {
            alert('This browser does not support the FileReader API.');
        }
    });

    // Upload the file.
    // You can upload files up to 2 GB with the REST API.
    function uploadFile() {

        // Define the folder path for this example.
        var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = '/Lists/Uploaded';

        // Get test values from the file input and text input page controls.
        var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
        var newName = jQuery('#displayName').val();

        // Get the server URL.
        var serverUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

        // Initiate method calls using jQuery promises.
        // Get the local file as an array buffer.
        var getFile = getFileBuffer();
        getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {

            // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
            var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer);
            addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {

                // Get the list item that corresponds to the uploaded file.
                var getItem = getListItem(file.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri);
                getItem.done(function (listItem, status, xhr) {

                    // Change the display name and title of the list item.
                    var changeItem = updateListItem(listItem.d.__metadata);
                    changeItem.done(function (data, status, xhr) {
                        alert('file uploaded and updated');
                    });
                    changeItem.fail(onError);
                });
                getItem.fail(onError);
            });
            addFile.fail(onError);
        });
        getFile.fail(onError);

        // Get the local file as an array buffer.
        function getFileBuffer() {
            var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
            }
            reader.onerror = function (e) {
                deferred.reject(e.target.error);
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[0]);
            return deferred.promise();
        }

        // Add the file to the file collection in the Shared Documents folder.
        function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer) {

            // Get the file name from the file input control on the page.
            var parts = fileInput[0].value.split('\\');
            var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

            // Construct the endpoint.
            var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
                    "{0}/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
                    "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')",
                    serverUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName);

            // Send the request and return the response.
            // This call returns the SharePoint file.
            return jQuery.ajax({
                url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
                type: "POST",
                data: arrayBuffer,
                processData: false,
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
                }
            });
        }

        // Get the list item that corresponds to the file by calling the file's ListItemAllFields property.
        function getListItem(fileListItemUri) {

            // Send the request and return the response.
            return jQuery.ajax({
                url: fileListItemUri,
                type: "GET",
                headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
            });
        }

        // Change the display name and title of the list item.
        function updateListItem(itemMetadata) {

            // Define the list item changes. Use the FileLeafRef property to change the display name. 
            // For simplicity, also use the name as the title. 
            // The example gets the list item type from the item's metadata, but you can also get it from the
            // ListItemEntityTypeFullName property of the list.
            var body = String.format("{{'__metadata':{{'type':'{0}'}},'FileLeafRef':'{1}','Title':'{2}'}}",
                itemMetadata.type, newName, newName);

            // Send the request and return the promise.
            // This call does not return response content from the server.
            return jQuery.ajax({
                url: itemMetadata.uri,
                type: "POST",
                data: body,
                headers: {
                    "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-length": body.length,
                    "IF-MATCH": itemMetadata.etag,
                    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Display error messages. 
    function onError(error) {
        alert(error.responseText);
    }

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label  for="SelectedFile"   class="control-label">Select document to upload</label>
                    <input id="getFile" type="file"/><br />
                    <input id="displayName" type="text" value="Enter a unique name" /><br />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="uploadFile()" id="SubmitDocument">submit</button>
                </div>
```

Now this works fine when I have breakpoints in chrome and debug. But when I dont have breakpoints enabled or when I dont have console opened, its just alerting **undefined**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your library name is "Uploaded".

You need to change the

```
var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = '/Lists/Uploaded';
```

to

```
var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = '/Uploaded';
```

Comment: but it works when i debug?